# VectorAssembler cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.feature.OneHotEncoder

Tags: java-8, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to cast a `VectorAssembler` to `OneHotEncoder` ?

The code below is the test that i mad.

```
Pipeline lPipeline = new Pipeline();
lPipeline.setStages(this.getPipelineStages());
OneHotEncoder lOHE1 = (OneHotEncoder)lPipeline.getStages()[2];
```

Comment: Read the docs at: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#onehotencoder

Comment: there is nothing about the cast